# Is there a sense to handle nullpointer exception by such way?

Tags: java, android

Is there a sense to handle null pointer exception by such way like

```
private void doWork(Object object) {
    if (object == null) {
        try {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean throw an exception merely so you can immediately catch it?

Comment: You are not handling any `NullPointerException`s there. Please be more clear.

Comment: @Felix, `NullPointerException` != "*a null pointer exception*" :-) He *is* handling the exceptional case where the argument equals a null pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, that code could be written more simply as:

```
private void doWork(Object object) {
    if (object == null) {
        new IllegalArgumentException().printStackTrace();
    } else {

    }
}
```

or (almost equivalently) as

```
private void doWork(Object object) {
    if (object == null) {
        Thread.dumpStack();
    } else {

    }
}
```

Second, is it doing something useful?  Yes, it is printing is a stack trace for the current thread.

Third, is it a good idea?  IMO, definitely NOT.

- It is sending stuff to the standard error, which may be going to the console (where it could be lost if nobody is watching) or to `/dev/null`.  Errors should be logged properly using your preferred logging subsystem.
- It *looks like* it is squashing a probable error condition (i.e. the program is broken because this method has been called with an illegal argument) and then continuing.  If this is really an error condition, then the code should probably be bailing out.  If it is not, then the stack trace is noise.

---

In short, this looks like a "bandaid" solution to some problem.  The correct solution is to remove this code (or replace it with code that simply throws `IllegalArgumentException`), and when the exception occurs figure out where it is coming from and *fix* the root problem.

Comment: You wrote that this is “definitely” a good idea, but it looks like you intended to say that it is *not* a good idea.

Comment: @Stuart Cook -  Indeed I did.  Fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: wouldn't a NullPointerException be more appropriate?

Comment: @Stephen C Pretty clear: Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required. ... Applications should throw instances of this class to indicate other illegal uses of the null object.

Comment: That is your opinion.  Other people (including, I presume, the original code author) would disagree.

Answer (score 10):

No, that doesn't really make sense.

Don't catch the exception. Just do

```
if (object == null)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument object may not equal null");
```

According to your suggestion the method would be document as

> *Do some work given argument `object`. If `object` is `null` it prints some garbage on standard out and does nothing else.*

---

As a side-note, since you're still learning Java, your try-catch block:

```
try {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

... is equivalent to ...

```
new IllegalArgumentException().printStackTrace();
```

Comment: It would be great to include which object was null in the errormessage.

Comment: Yes, but if you see in the log just this error message and you have multiple of them, you still don0t know where the error was.

Comment: Ah now I see what you meant. It was my fault, you cant do something like object.toString() in the error message if object is null. Sry.

Comment: @Roflcoptr - *which object was null* ?? An object can't be `null` ;)

Comment: Nope, you can't ;-)  ...removing my comments.

Comment: My goals:
- stable app
- useful information in log
So, I think:
`code
private void doWork(Object object) {<br/>
    if (object == null) {<br/>
        new IllegalArgumentException().printStackTrace();<br/>
    } else {<br/>
        ...<br/>
    }<br/>
}<br/>`

will be optimal solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's fine to throw an exception if a `null` is an exceptional state, but the try/catch does not make much sense: you `throw` a `new IllegalArgumentException();`, `catch` it right afterwards, print a stacktrace an continue.

If you can handle the `null` case and just want to report, then you should write it to a log file:

```
if (object == null) {
  log.warn("method doWork has been called with a null argument");
}
// continue in the method
```

Otherwise the method should throw the exception back at it's caller

```
if (object == null) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Hey stupid, RTFJD, NO calls with null!");
}
```

(replace exception message with something meaningful ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

```
private void throwIfNull(Object object, String message) throws NullPointerException {
    if (object == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException(message);
    }
}
```

Then you can specify your method to throw the exception back to the caller, like so

```
private void doWork(Object object) throws Exception {
    throwIfNull(object, "Object is null");

    //Other work....
    doWorkInternal(object);
}
```

In this case, you know that if `doWorkInternal()` method is called, the object was **never** null.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is

```
if (object != null) {
  doWork();
} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to catch the exception inside your function and let some calling function to handle this,

its better to do this :

```
public void doWork(Object object) throws NullPointerException {
  //code that might result NullPointerException. 
  //no handling of exception by yourself
}
```

But if want/should handle the exception within the definition of your method, 
your code is good.

Answer (score -3):

When object came as null, it will automatically throw an null pointer exception. but you didn't handle it, and you are trying to throw an "IllegalArgumentException()", which isn't possible.

if (object == null)
this line itself, an exception is thrown, and it won't execute the rest of the line.

Comment: This advice is incorrect. Merely testing an object reference against `null` does not throw any kind of exception, and it is perfectly possible to `throw new IllegalArgumentException()`.